# Getting a warning message while creating a REST API in IBM IIB V 10.0.0.7

Tags: swagger, ibm-integration-bus

I am getting the below warning message in the automatically generated REST API message flow while creating a REST API (by importing a swagger document) -

"This message flow is automatically generated.
Do not edit this message flow.
If you edit the message flow, your changes will be overwritten without a warning."

The IBM Integration Bus version we are using is V 10.0.0.7

What's the significance of this error? And under what conditions, code (what code) will be overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

You should make the necessary changes using REST API Description. Message flow is generated from this description, so it will be overridden the next time something in REST API Description changes and the message flow is regenerated.

Edit: You can add a subflow to handle errors using error handling in your REST API Description:

[image]

Comment: Our requirement is to add some common subflows like exception and logging in the main auto generated message flow. What would be the best approach to do that?

Comment: You can add a subflow for exception handling as shown in the edit to my post. For logging, I would advise creating a subflow and calling it from each  subflow in the main flow, instead of adding it to the main flow.

Comment: The flow is embedded to the node in the flow so its advisable not to change it because you will have issues at deployment that you will not be able to resolve.....its IIB internal design